# Teradata update trigger not fired on adding new column

Tags: sql, triggers, teradata

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE x (
 id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
 name VARCHAR(255),
 last_updated TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
);
```

with a BEFORE UPDATE trigger to automatically set the value of last_updated to the timestamp of last modification of the row:

```
CREATE TRIGGER x_trig_bu
BEFORE UPDATE ON x
REFERENCING NEW AS newrow
FOR EACH ROW
SET newrow.last_updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0);
```

However, when I create a new column in the table (ALTER TABLE x ADD dummy CHAR(2) DEFAULT 'YN', last_updated does not change.

How can I update automatically last_updated when a column is being added or removed from the table?

Comment: I don't believe a BEFORE TRIGGER will fire with a DDL statement against the table. However, the data dictionary table has a timestamp column called LastAlterTimeStamp that captures the point in which the last DDL statement was issued against the table. There should also be a column called RequestText which captures the DDL statement that was issued against the table. (i.e. DROP INDEX, ALTER TABLE, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute trigger only on INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE.
There is no option to execute trigger on ALTER TABLE.

There is a table dbc.tables that contains info on when table was last time changes, you can try to set trigger on that.